# Why does react function in ReactClass get called repeatedly on form input change events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react-bootstrap React Class, where the createList function gets called on every key input to either of the form inputs (workDone, or hoursAndMinutes).  I'm new to reactjs, and perhaps this is normal behavior, but it seems to me that it isn't, and hence I'm doing something wrong.

```
var SubjectBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return({
      totalHoursAndMinute:0,
      subject:'',
      workDone:'',
      hoursAndMinutes:'',

    })
  },
  dropDownSelected:function(e){
    this.setState({subject:e.target.value})
  },
  handleChangeToWorkDone(){
    let s = this.refs.workDone.getValue();
    console.log(s);
    this.setState({
      workDone: s
    });
  },
  validateWorkDone:function(){
    let length = this.state.workDone.length;
    if (length >= 10) return 'success';
    else if (length > 5) return 'warning';
    else if (length > 0) return 'error';
  },
  validateHoursAndMinutes(){
    let hm = this.state.hoursAndMinutes.split(':');
    if (hm.length === 2){
      return 'success';
    }else{
      return 'error';
    }
  },
  handleChangeToHoursMinute(){
    var minutes =0;
    let s =this.refs.hoursAndMinutes.getValue();
    let hm =  s.split(':');
    if (hm.length===2){
      var h = parseInt(hm[0].trim());
      var m = parseInt(hm[1].trim());
      if (!m.isNaN){
        var minutes = h*60+m;
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      hoursAndMinutes: s,
      totalMinutes:minutes
    });
  },
  createList: function(){
    console.log("create list function.");
    var list=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.subjects.length;i++){
      list.push(<option key={i} value={this.props.subjects[i].subject}>{this.props.subjects[i].subject}</option>)
    }
    return list;
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.workDone);
    console.log(this.state.subject);
  },
  render(){
    return(

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input ref="subjectList" type="select" label="Subject" onChange={this.dropDownSelected}>
            {this.createList()}
          </Input>
          <Input ref="workDone"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.workDone}
            placeholder="What did you do?"
            label="What did you do" help="Input is 10 or more characters."
            bsStyle={this.validateWorkDone()}  hasFeedback
            groupClassName="group-class" labelClassName="label-class"
            onChange={this.handleChangeToWorkDone} />
          <Input ref="hoursAndMinutes"
            type="text" value={this.state.hoursAndMinutes}  placeholder="HH:MM?"
            label="How long did you do it?"  help="Input in hours:minutes, example 1:5 = an hour and five minutes."
            bsStyle={this.validateHoursAndMinutes()}  hasFeedback
            groupClassName="group-class"
            labelClassName="label-class"   onChange={this.handleChangeToHoursMinute} />
          <Button type="submit" bsStyle="success">Submit</Button>
        </form>

    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you are using in `handleChangeToWorkDone` and `handleChangeToWorkDone` [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) which calls `re-render`

> `setState()` will always trigger a re-render unless conditional
>   rendering logic is implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`. If mutable
>   objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in
>   `shouldComponentUpdate()`, calling `setState()` only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

In React Js, the HTML/DOM is always just a representation on the State of your React Component.

Whenever there is a onChange or onBlur or any event, if the State of the React Component is changed(using setState func), the ReactJs component is re-rendered(using Render func).

Only when the State of the React Js component changes, your UI can be updated with the value you key in. Hence, It is the expected behaviour in React Js.